# Default.png won't display, iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a really standard splash screen, just a simple Default.png, but for whatever reason, no matter what I try, it simply will not load. Is there any way to fix this and/or a way to set a property in tw info.plist to directly call a custom image? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your image is 480x320 pixels, and placed in your application at the top level. The frameworks will display this image until your initial view has loaded and is ready for display.

If you are seeing a black background then there is something amiss, however if you are just seeing your app's initial view then be happy you have managed to launch your app and have it ready for use in good time.

If you really, really want the user to to see your splash screen then slow down your launch by adding a delay into your app before you present the initial view

Answer (score 2):

It is very important to name the file "Default.png" and not "default.png". Capital letter at the front. Make sure you rename the actual filename and not just the image name in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Images.xcassets to manage you images,make sure the "2x" of "iPhone portrait iOS7"  exit and be set as 640 × 1136.It's really useful if you are seeing a black background instead of the image named Defualt.png.

Answer (score -1):

It was a simple case problem mixed with a refresh problem.  Setting the case correctly and "CLEAN" the solution fixed the problem.